# Assigning onClick button to the proper feature. Map function ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I created this mockup and I am trying to put this into real life
[component mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oslLq.png)

I started from something simple so I created 3 buttons and an array
but what happens is that when I click on any button I see all of the features, and my goal was to when I click on SMS I see sms.features etc. But for now I see this that way [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvHFz.png)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isHidden: true,
      features: [
        {
          name: "sms.features",
          key: "1",
          icon: "sms icon"
        },
        {
          name: "pricing.features",
          key: "2",
          icon: "pricing icon"
        },
        {
          name: "api.features",
          key: "3",
          icon: "api icon"
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          name: "sms",
          key: 1
        },
        {
          name: "pricing",
          key: 2
        },
        {
          name: "api",
          key: 3
        }
      ]
    };
    this.toggleHidden = this.toggleHidden.bind(this);
  }

  toggleHidden() {
    this.setState({
      isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginLeft: "20%" }}>
        <div className="features__details__grid">
          {!this.state.isHidden &&
            this.state.features.map((object, key) => (
              <div key={key}>{object.name}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div className="buttons">
          {this.state.buttons.map((button, key) => (
            <div key={key}>
              <button onClick={this.toggleHidden}>{button.name}</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since you want to show only one, the `isHidden` should really be a pointer to which feature should be visible (*by targeting the `key` property*)

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visibleFeature: "0",
      features: [
        {
          name: "sms.features",
          key: "1",
          icon: "sms icon"
        },
        {
          name: "pricing.features",
          key: "2",
          icon: "pricing icon"
        },
        {
          name: "api.features",
          key: "3",
          icon: "api icon"
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          name: "sms",
          key: "1"
        },
        {
          name: "pricing",
          key: "2"
        },
        {
          name: "api",
          key: "3"
        }
      ]
    };
    this.toggleHidden = this.toggleHidden.bind(this);
  }

  toggleHidden(key) {
    this.setState(state=>{
      if (state.visibleFeature === key) return {visibleFeature: 0}
      
      return {visibleFeature: key}
    });
  }

  render() {
    const feature = this.state.visibleFeature;
    return (
      <div style={{ marginLeft: "20%" }}>
        <div className="features__details__grid">
          {this.state.features.map((object) => (
              feature === object.key && <div key={object.key}>{object.name}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div className="buttons">
          {this.state.buttons.map((button) => (
            <div key={button.key}>
              <button onClick={()=>this.toggleHidden(button.key)}>{button.name}</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/8y5q120wxj

Comment: hey, I just realised that I never thank you for this respond, it helped me a lot at that point! Thank You!

Comment: @Wiola You are welcome. You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if you intend on hanging around SO :)